# Bluetooth keyboard to unlock encrypted disk (20.10)

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, disk, unlock

I have found discussions of this issue, but no solution, so far.
What needs to be done to have a bluetooth keyboard paired (BCM20730 chipset) to provide the password for an encrypted disk?